# Is there any posibility to delete multiple members of a group with microsoft graph?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, httprequest, azure-ad-b2c

In the official documentation there is an example to make a DELETE request in order to delete a member from a group. Here's the documentation - [remove member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/members/{directory-object-id}/$ref
```

So far from what i've found and tested, when adding an user to a group, you can add up to 20 users per request, into a group. [add member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 30

{
  "members@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
    ]
}
```

I was wondering if there is any possibility to remove multiple users from a group per request, or if you could remove 20 users at a time from a group, per request, like you can do when you're adding them into a group.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, after my test, you cannot delete multiple members in a group through Microsoft Graph, you can only delete a single member. You can make your suggestions [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple requests in one HTTP call using JSON batching ([check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching)). But JSON batch requests are currently limited to 20 individual requests.